# Encapsulate two express apps within one

Tags: javascript, express

I'm looking for a way to have independent apps within express that have their own `notFound` and `error` handlers. I need a way to encapsulate all routes so that they don't effect subsequent routes.

I've tried using apps directly,

```
const apiOne = express()
apiOne.get('/api-one/hello', helloApiOne)
apiOne.use(notFoundHandler)
apiOne.use(errorHandler)

const apiTwo = express()
apiTwo.get('/api-two/hello', helloApiTwo)
apiTwo.use(notFoundHandler)
apiTwo.use(errorHandler)

const app = express()
app.get(apiOne)
app.use(apiTwo)
```

And I've also tried using routers.

```
const apiOne = express.Router()
apiOne.get('/api-one/hello', helloApiOne)
apiOne.use(notFoundHandler)
apiOne.use(errorHandler)

const apiTwo = express.Router()
apiTwo.get('/api-two/hello', helloApiTwo)
apiTwo.use(notFoundHandler)
apiTwo.use(errorHandler)

const app = express()
app.get(apiOne)
app.use(apiTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mounting them a bit differently? Using the router i believe you can segment them and have error handlers on that router execute first.

```
const apiOne = express.Router()
apiOne.get('/hello', helloApiOne)
apiOne.use(notFoundHandler)
apiOne.use(errorHandler)

const apiTwo = express.Router()
apiTwo.get('/hello', helloApiTwo)
apiTwo.use(notFoundHandler)
apiTwo.use(errorHandler)

const app = express()
app.use('/api-one', apiOne)
app.use('/api-two', apiTwo)
```

Comment: I am aware of this. I was looking for a solution that would allow each app to be independent of path name-spacing like this.

Comment: By your example, they're already independent path names. If you want them to be on the same path, I recommend providing a single error route, that then delegates to a different error handler based on path or whatever criteria you are using